# Separate list of Common_noun proper noun and location in python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, named-entity-recognition

I have a list of words and I need to find out which words fall in the categories *proper noun*, *common noun* and *location*. I would like to have a table where each category has its proper column.

My input is as follows:

```
abatable
abate
abated
abatement
abatements
abbots
abbreviate
abbreviated
abbreviates
```

So far, I have tried the code below, which returns a list of nouns but I also need to add verbs and locations. How can this be done?

```
import nltk
File = open("C:\\Desktop\\English_words_Filtered_golve.csv")
lines = File.read()
sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(lines)
nouns = []

for sentence in sentences:
     for word,pos in nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(str(sentence))):
         if (pos == 'NN' or pos == 'NNP' or pos == 'NNS' or pos == 'NNPS'):
             nouns.append(word)

print(nouns)
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Please provide some code what you have already tried.

Comment: i have added the code @ChW

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dictionary like this:

```
words={'noun':[],...}
for word,pos in nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(str(sentence))):
   if (pos == 'NN' or pos == 'NNP' or pos == 'NNS' or pos == 'NNPS'):
      words['noun']=word
   elif ...
```